# Subscribe with parameters with Meteor-Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am new to *Meteor* and I am trying to build an online reporting app with `angular-meteor` but I am having problems trying to `publish` and `subscribe` with parameter(s).

In **lib/collections.js**,

```
TestReport = new Mongo.Collection('test_report');
```

In **server/publications.js**,

```
Meteor.publish('testReportDetail', function(reportID) {
    check(reportID, String);

    return TestReport.findOne({_id: reportID});
});
```

In **client/test_report_detail.js**,

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $reactive, $stateParams) {
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.subscribe('testReportDetail', $stateParams.reportID);

    this.helpers({
        reportDetail: function() {
            return TestReport.find({_id: $stateParams.reportID});
        }
    });
});
```

When client browser tries to access *report detail* it gets the error in console

`typeError: fn is not a function`

Any idea...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a fix for `this.subscribe` in the new 1.3.1 release I've just published, please check again - https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/releases

Answer (score 0):

In **server/publications.js** you should be using find() instead of findOne().

```
Meteor.publish('testReportDetail', function(reportID) {
    check(reportID, String);

    return TestReport.find({_id: reportID});
});
```

Although the signatures of those two functions are similar, they return very different things! find() will return a cursor, but findOne() actually returns an object.

Here's the relevant [documentation for Meteor.publish()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish).

Also see [documentation for Collections.find()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have tried replacing with `find()` but it still doesn't work...any other ideas?